# Core search is not searching content in the node which is fetched through an entity reference field

Tags: search

Core search in Drupal 7 not searching the content in the node which has been fetched through an entity reference field.

What could be the solution to search for a keyword in all pages of the website?

Would there be any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

The search index is build from a special view mode for nodes, called 'search_index'.

The easiest way to configure this is

- Install/enable [Entity View Modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode)
- Enable configuration of the 'search_index' view mode for your content type.  I believe it will appear as a tab under /admin/structure/types/manage/page
- Configure the 'search_index' at /admin/structure/types/manage/page/display/search_index
- Add/remove fields as needed.  For your entity reference, change the display to "rendered entity".

Clear the search index, and rebuild it.

Comment: This is going by memory, as I am not sure if I have any Drupal 7 left that do this.  Some details may need to be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Will try this and let you know

Comment: Yes, now its searching content referenced through entity reference field .Thank you.